# looping arraylist of combination takes time kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Double loop takes much time in kotlin. I have a list of words (some times list contain 100k+ words). I want to search through my product list contains list in words. How can I improve the following code? It causes anr if combination of words increased.

```
private fun getProductListFromCombinations(combination:List<String>): List<ProductEntity> {
    val arrayList=  mutableListOf<ProductEntity>()


        for (comb in combination){

            val searchedList = listAllProduct.filter {

                    obj -> obj.name.contains(comb,true)

            }

            arrayList.addAll(searchedList)

        }



    return arrayList.distinct()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private fun getProductListFromCombinations(combination: List<String>): List<ProductEntity> {

    return listAllProduct.filter { productEntity ->

        combination.any { it.contains(productEntity.name, true) }
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: i will check bro

Comment: I think it should be `productEntity.name.contains(it, true)`